# PHP exec() cannot run GhostScript

Tags: php, exec, mamp

I'm trying to use a library that requires to exec() GhostScript, but it fails to do so on my MAMP server. I've written this small piece of code to run tests:

```
<?php 
$cmd = "...";
$output = array();
exec($cmd, $output)
echo $output[0];
?>
```

First, I've set `$cmd` to `'whoami'` and it works and gives the same result in PHP and in Terminal (my username).

Then I tried with `'/usr/texbin/latex --version'` and it works fine too.

But when I try with `'/opt/local/bin/gs --version'`, it fails whereas it works in terminal.

It seems to me that it is neither a PATH problem or a apache authorization problem (the usual suspects from what I've read so far), so I'm running out of ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is safe_mode / safe_mode_exec_dir set? http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode-exec-dir

Comment: looks like authorization problem to me. why don't you try to make a symbolic link in the folder of your php file and give it the right authorization

Comment: @MichaelMacDonald: I'm on PHP 5.4.10 so these don't exist anymore.

@ITroubs: I made a `ln -s /opt/local/bin/gs gs` from the directory where my file is, but I'm not sure how to change the authorization?

Comment: @ITroubs Permissions on symlink casnnot be more permissive that target, or rather it wont matter. The target decides what can be done in the end anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Although a few years old, but anyway. I had the same problem today (tried to run ghostscript using php exec() on Ubuntu 14.4, meaning not mamp, but rather separate installs of apache, php, tesseract, ghostscript etc. required), and managed to solve it by creating a bash shell script in which I run the gs with parameters, and then run the sh script with php exec().

The row in my bash shell script:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -r300 -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile=/var/www/html/ykinv/jpg/${theFile}
```

And the php exec row from my php script:

```
exec("sh pdf2jpgConversion.sh");
```

The scripts all reside in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue when using exec() or shell_exec() to run Ghostscript command. I got the following error:

```
gs: /opt/lampp/lib/libtiff.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgs.so.9) gs: /opt/lampp/lib/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16)
```

Setting up the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable solved it for me.

```
<?php

$command = 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="' . $path_to_library_dir .'"; ' . $path_to_binary;
shell_exec($command);

?>
```

In my Ubuntu 18.04 $path_to_library_dir is "`/usr/share/ghostscript/9.26/lib`"
and $path_to_binary is "`/usr/bin/gs`"

You can verify library files path by executing `gs --help`  command in terminal.
For verification of path_to_binary use `which gs`

Answer (score -1):

`shell_exec` rather than `exec` worked for me

Comment: please consider the following : [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -4):

```
Try this.

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$pdf='test.pdf';
$quality=90;
$res='300x300';
$exportName="pdf_export_" . time();
$exportPath=realpath(dirname(__FILE__))."/$exportName/fullres/%03d.jpg";

mkdir(realpath(dirname(__FILE__))."/$exportName");
mkdir(realpath(dirname(__FILE__))."/$exportName/fullres");

set_time_limit(900);
exec("'gs' '-dNOPAUSE' '-sDEVICE=jpeg' '-dUseCIEColor' '-dTextAlphaBits=4' '-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4' '-o$exportPath' '-r$res' '-dJPEGQ=$quality' '$pdf'",$output);
```

Comment: -1, you should attribute your work to the original author: http://www.veryinteractivepeople.com/?p=521